# Service consumption and whiteboard pattern

Tags: osgi

Whiteboard pattern is used pervasively in OSGI. I have one doubt related to it that I hope you'll help to clear.

I have a component P implementing service Plugin. The service is modifying a system component R (which consumes all services of type Plugin as a dynamic reference) and its behaviour.

Now I have a service X that depends on R and relies on this modified behaviour.
I need to be sure that P has actually been picked by R before I can use it in X. So far did that by depending on P in all components that consumed R.

Now I'm not sure that is enough, as the assumption is that once P goes online, bind methods of all components that depend in it are called before any components are actually activated.

I haven't spotted any piece of OSGI spec that guarantees that. 
If it's not is there any way to know that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right, this is not a safe situation. Although the OSGi parts are done perfect, the work R does on P creates a race condition.

So the best solution is ...  the whiteboard. If possible, register X as a whiteboard service picked up by R. It is then R's responsibility to pickup P, treat them appropriately, and then call X. This is not trivial code to do it right since you can get `add(P)/remove(P)` simultaneously with `add(X)/remove(X)`. That would then be a nice other SO question :-)

If you cannot change R then there is no good solution I am aware of because you have a hidden dependency. R creates a new situation for P but does not provide a proper point where you react.